# How can i have controls binded to a property change when the property changes internally?

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to bind a control to a property of instance. however, this property will change internally, so `INotifyPropertyChanged` somehow just doesn't work.

for example, i want to show how many elements currently exists in a certain container. so my choice is binding `Count` to a label or what. but even the `Count` property has changed to another number, UI won't change.

i don't want to have wrapper classes for everything, since wrapper won't solve a subset of problems. another example is if i want to know how long it takes for a Timer to expire,  it changes internally, i could not even have a wrapper to help me.

so what's the general way to solve this when what to bind control to whatever property?

Comment: It would nice to see a peace of code to understand what exactly is your problem. Timer has event. If there is no event or bindable property, then you still can poll value.

Comment: have you looked at BindingSource..? [How to: Raise Change Notifications Using a BindingSource and the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms184414(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways.

You can use the databindings property of the control you want to bind to. The following should guide you to a better answer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings(v=vs.110).aspx

Optionally, you can use custom events, and simply register those events on the form that has the control. When an event fires, handle the event where ever necessary.

Example:

In your model class:

```
class myModel
{
   public event EventHandler OnNameChanged(object sender, NameChangedEventArgs e); = delegate { };

   private _name;
   public string Name 
   { 
      get { return _name; } 
      set 
      {
         _name = value;

         if (OnNameChanged != null)
            OnNameChanged(this, new NameChangedEventArgs(value))
      } 
   }
}

public class NameChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
   private _name;

   public NameChangedEventArgs(string name) { _name = name; }
   public Name { get { return _name; } }
}
```

Then in your form, register to the event:

```
public class form1
{
   private myModel model;

   public form()
   {
      Initialize();
   }

   private void Initialize()
   {
      model.OnNameChanged += new EventHandler(model_OnNameChangedEvent);
   }

   private void model_OnNamedChangedEvent(object sender, NameChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      textbox.text = e.Name;
   }
}
```

So now, when the model.Name changes, the model's OnNameChanged event fires. Any object that has registered to that event can handle it in their own way.